# How much space do I need to upgrade my desktop from Fedora13 to Fedora14

Tags: upgrade, yum

I want to use yum. It will download package from repositories.

I know it depends on packages that I have installed.

How could I calculate the space needed ?

Comment: Why do you need to know this info?

Comment: My disks are almost full. I would like to know how much data (films, music...) I have to put on DVD. I know I should backup everything but I'm too lazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `preupgrade` it will do all the hard work for you, and download a local repository of what needs updated.  It will calculate what is needed and let you know if you need more space.

Comment: It will also use anaconda instead of yum though.